# How can a static method be called dynamically from an instance method?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, scope, encapsulation

I have several classes, each of which should be able to retrieve an existing instance of itself (using an ID) when possible, rather than creating a new instance. For encapsulation and convenience, I want to store each class’s library as a static property of the class, and abstract the whole pattern for quick reuse. But **I can’t find a clean way to *dynamically* access a *static* method from an *instance* scope in JS.**

```js
class HasLibrary
{
    static library = new Map();
    static retrieve(id) { return new this(id); }

    constructor(id) {
        let existing = HasLibrary.library.get(id);
        if (existing) return existing;

        this.id = id;
        HasLibrary.set(id, this);

        return false; // for inheritance
    }
}

class Tag extends HasLibrary
{
    constructor(name, options) {
        let existing = super(name);
        if (existing) return existing;
        
        // do Tag-specific stuff

        return this;
    }
}

class Product extends HasLibrary
{
    constructor(name, options) {
        let existing = super(name);
        if (existing) return existing;
        
        // do Product-specific stuff

        return this;
    }
}
```

The static `retrieve()` function inherits correctly, so I can call `Tag.retrieve("spruce")` and it returns a Tag instance. (In OOP terms, I can access instance methods dynamically from static methods.) But of course, when Tag calls `super()`, the library property is hard-coded to the base class.

If this were (modern) PHP, I could call the static keyword to get the *current* class’s property.

```php
abstract class HasLibrary
{
    ...

    function __construct($id) {
        $result = static::$library[$id];
        ...
```

I’ve resorted to setting an *instance* property that each of the child classes must override, but there’s still more copy-paste action required than I would prefer. (In addition, the static library property does not create new Maps when inherited, so that Tag.library and Product.library point to the same Map.)

```js
class HasLibrary
{
    static retrieve(id) { return new this(id); }

    id = '';

    constructor(id) {
        let existing = this.self.library.get(id);
        if (existing) return existing;

        this.id = id;
        this.self.library.set(id, this);

        return false; // for inheritance
    }
}

class Tag extends HasLibrary
{
    static library = new Map();
    get self() { return Tag; }

    constructor(name, options) {
        let existing = super(name);
        if (existing) return existing;
        
        // do Tag-specific stuff

        return this;
    }
}

class Product extends HasLibrary
{
    static library = new Map();
    get self() { return Product; }

    constructor(name, options) {
        let existing = super(name);
        if (existing) return existing;
        
        // do Product-specific stuff

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure `return false; // for inheritance` does what you believe it does?

Comment: @jaromanda I believe `super()` modifies `this` directly, so it doesn't depend on returning an object. Instead, I use the return as a flag (truthy or false) for the early return pattern of constructors that inherit it.

Comment: "*I’ve resorted to setting an instance property that each of the child classes must override*" - you're looking for `this.constructor`, which is more or less the same as your `this.self`. See also the duplicate "*In addition, the static library property does not create new Maps when inherited, so that `Tag.library` and `Product.library` point to the same Map.*" - yes, they both refer to `HasLibrary.library`; and there's not really a way around that. Each class will need to explicitly decide which `.library` to use. To avoid mistakes, I would recommend not setting it on `HasLibrary` itself.